# How to make search faster in millions of data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have millions of records in database, we need to search TOP 50 records on the basis of some conditions.

Here is the filter criteria:
where clause having different columns of different table.

```
WHERE e.event_id NOT IN (
            SELECT Event_Id
            FROM [dbo].Event_Table eeii
            WHERE eeii.Submitted_By != 524
                AND eeii.STATUS = 'Draft'
                AND eeii.ActivityCompletedIndicator IS NULL
            )
        AND e.Event_Id > 0

        AND CONTAINS (
            e.Event_Id_SearchString
            ,'"*4*"'
            )
        AND CONTAINS (
            e.Event_Name
            ,'"*a*"'
            )
        AND e.STATUS IN (
            'Not Submitted'
            ,'Draft'
            )
        AND e.Event_Type_Id = 2
        AND e.Country_Id IN (22)
        AND sm.State_Name LIKE N'%A%'
        AND CONTAINS (
            e.External_Activity_ID
            ,'"*P*"'
            )
        AND u.FirstName LIKE N'%a%'
        AND u.LastName LIKE N'%a%'
        AND ai.Attendee_FName LIKE N'%a%'
        AND ai.Attendee_LName LIKE N'%a%'
        AND ai.Fullname_organizationName LIKE N'%a%'
        AND ai.CustomerID LIKE N'%P%'
        AND EX.SpendItemid = 1
        AND epi.Product_Id = 18
        AND e.Total_Amount = 789
        AND e.CurrencyId = 11
        AND e.Payment_ID = 1826
```

We have used Full Text Index on those column where we can manage to use.
We have created required index for other columns.

Note : We have used APPLYs instead of JOINs, So that we can not use full text Index for other table which are combined using APPLYs

Still not getting expected performance.

Please suggest.

Comment: read some whitepapers on [Full text  indexing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(v=sql.100).aspx)  for best practices and also try to get more info on how sites like SO uses search

Comment: Thanks for reply.....Other thanFull text index, How we can make it faster.

Comment: I am not sure, see posts from so or other sites and see how they are using search

Comment: Millions of data... You are performing many `LIKE %something%`... This **must** be slow... You might try to write small subsets of your big tables into table variables or temp tables first and join on smaller sets. But - normally - SQL Server is very good in finding the best execution plan. Are there scalar operations taking place in your `SELECT`'s column list?

Comment: SELECT Statement : `SELECT Row_Number() OVER (
   ORDER BY e.event_id DESC
   ) AS RowNumber
  ,e.CustomerId
  ,e.GrandTotal AS Total_Amount
  ,e.Total_Amount AS FormattedAmount
  ,cr.CurrencyName AS CurrencyName
  ,e.Event_Id
  ,e.event_name
  ,u.username AS Submitted_By
  ,e.event_date
  ,e.request_date AS request_date
  ,e.External_Activity_ID
  ,e.Submitted_By AS SubmittedBy_ID
  ,E.STATUS AS Event_Status`